# When do I need to upgrade to Windows 10 by to take advantage of the free upgrade?

Tags: windows-10, windows-10-upgrade

When do I need to upgrade to Windows 10 by from Windows 7?

The reason I'm asking is because Windows keeps giving me an error when I try to update my ASI when in the US.

Comment: If you have an actual computer question about your error, then please make a question about that (the actual computer problem) rather than requesting the info you've asked for - which is easily available with a simple search: http://windows.microsoft.com/en-ca/windows/lifecycle

Comment: It's a reference to the free update.

Comment: Then you should clarify that in your question. It sounds like you are asking about Windows 7 lifecycle. The answer you want is also easily searchable, it's in the Windows 10 FAQ. http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/windows-10-faq `you have until July 29, 2016 to take advantage of this offer`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> It is available for a limited time: you have until **July 29, 2016** to take advantage of this offer. Once you upgrade, you’ll have Windows 10 for free on that device.

Source: [Windows 10 FAQ](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/windows-10-faq) under **Is the upgrade really free?**

Answer (score 3):

### When will Microsoft stop supporting Windows 7 SP1?

End of mainstream support: **January 13, 2015**

End of extended support: **January 14, 2020**

### When will Microsoft stop supporting Windows 8.1 Update?

End of mainstream support: **January 9, 2018**

End of extended support: **January 10, 2023**

### When will the free upgrade offer to Windows 10 expire for users running Windows 7 SP1 and Windows 8.1 Update?

> This is a full version of Windows, not a trial or introductory
>   version. It is available for a limited time: you have until July 29,
>   2016 to take advantage of this offer. Once you upgrade, you’ll have
>   Windows 10 for free on that device.  You can [learn more here](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/windows-10-faq#ui-id-17).

[Windows 10 FAQ](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/windows-10-faq)

### Windows 10, released in July 2015 Lifecycle

End of mainstream support: **October 13, 2020**

End of extended support: **October 14, 2025**

[Windows Lifecycle](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/lifecycle)

Comment: The question was modified during the writing of this answer.  I attempted to answer what I thought the user was asking.